# Can EF select multiple transformed collections?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Say I have an entity called Request that has collections of child entities like below:

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to retrieve an object containing both the Tasks and Questions collections and I could do this using `include()` but I don't need all the fields from those collections.

Say I'm only interested in retrieving a Name and Date field from each `Task` and `Question` entity.

The only way I know how to do this is by calling `select()` in multiple queries to retrieve each transformed collection.

Is there a way to do this in a single trip to the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
var requests = context.Request
                      .Select(r => new 
                              {
                                id = R.RequestID,
                                tasks = R.Tasks
                                         .Select(t => new
                                                      {
                                                        Name = t.Name,
                                                        Date = t.Date
                                                      });                  
                                questions = R.Questions
                                             .Select(q => new
                                                          {
                                                            Name = q.Name,
                                                            Date = q.Date
                                                          });                  
                              });
```

I'm pretty sure `Include` is not required because query itself is already joining in order to return the joined items.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I was over complicating it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not exactly what you're looking for, but this should only be one round-trip to the database, and should get you started in the right direction:

```
entitycontext.Requests.Select(t => new {
   TaskName = t.Questions.First().Name,
   QuestionName = t.Tasks.First().Name
});
```